# mysql - using if in subquery to CONCAT

Tags: mysql

I trying to write a query to correct an error in a DATETIME field in a table, but my subquery can return NULL as transactiondetails and CreateDate field needs to have a valid value.

My current query is this one:

```sql
UPDATE transactionsheaders H SET CreateDate = 
    CONCAT(
    DATE((SELECT CreateDate FROM transactionsdetails WHERE TransactionUID=H.UID GROUP BY TransactionUID)),
    ' ',
    TIME(CreateDate)) 
WHERE UID>0;
```

and I want to use the result of

```sql
SELECT CreateDate FROM transactionsdetails WHERE TransactionUID=H.UID GROUP BY TransactionUID
```

if it isn't **NULL** and **DATE(CreateDate)** otherwise.

I've been trying to use **IF** for this purpose, but I am having problems writing something that works...

One more thing, **transactionsdetails** refers to **transactionsheaders** through **TransactionUID** (1 to many). Is **GROUP BY** guaranteed to return only one result?

Comment: why not run simpler update query only for records where it's null? and then another one for those where CreateDate is wrong? you don't always have to combine all the logic into 1 query..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the correct thing

```
UPDATE transactionsheaders H
SET CreateDate = CONCAT(DATE(ifnull((SELECT
                       CreateDate
                     FROM transactionsdetails
                     WHERE TransactionUID = H.UID
                     GROUP BY TransactionUID)),'2012-02-02'), ' ', TIME(CreateDate))
WHERE UID > 0;
```

You can set any default value insted of '2012-02-02' or even date(now())

Comment: Shouldn't this affect all rows? 98 row(s) affected
Rows matched: 45922  Changed: 98  Warnings: 0

Comment: Forget it, It's working as it should. It only updates if it's different. Right?